# Event Listener in PHP

Tags: php, events, webserver, tcpserver

I want my **web server to notify me through a php page when an event occurs at another TCP server, to which the PHP page has successfully connected** via a socket. The event is like the TCP server wants to send a message to the web server, etc. Is there any way to accomplish this and/or any references on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
$fp = fsockopen("tcp://example.com", 8888) OR die("could not connect");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $pc = fread($handle, 8192);
    if ($pc === false || strlen($pc) == 0)
        break;
    //a new packet has arrived
    //you should collect the read in a variable and wait
    //for another packet until you know the message is complete
    //(depends on the protocol)
    collect_in_result($pc);
    if (message_is_complete()) {
        if (check_event()) {
            //take action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please explain what happens in this code please?

Comment: See the manual entries for fsockopen and fread (http://www.php.net/fsockopen and http://www.php.net/fread). I've fixed an error, `fsockopen` must be used in place of `fopen`.